# Setting columns width with PHP_XLSXWriter

Tags: php, xls

I can't figure out how to set columns width with PHP_XLSXWriter.

I tryed :

```
$widths = array(10,20,30,40,50,60);
$col_options = array('widths'=>$widths);
$writer->writeSheetHeader($sheet, $header, $suppress_header_row = true, $col_options );
```

and :

```
$writer->writeSheetHeader($sheet, $header, $suppress_header_row = true, $col_options = ['widths'=>[10,20,30,40,50,60]] );
```

None are working. What am I doing wrong ?

By the way if there is a way to automatically adjust columns width to data lengths, it would be great !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the suppress_row option in the option array :

```
$writer->writeSheetHeader($sheet, $header, $col_options = ['widths'=>[10,20,30,40,50,60], 'suppress_row'=>true] );
```

Comment: In other words, the only way to set column widths is to actually write a row (with mandatory text and all) and at the same time delete the row with the `suppress_row` attribute? Honestly this plugin leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 2):

Try without the $supress_header_row argument:

```
$widths = array(10,20,30,40,50,60);
$writer->writeSheetHeader($sheet, $header, $col_options = ['widths'=>[10,20,30,40,50,60]] );
```

UPDATE:
Pretty sure to suppress the first row you add that to col_options now:

```
$writer->writeSheetHeader($sheet, $header, $col_options = ['widths'=>[10,20,30,40,50,60], 'suppress_row' => 1] );
```

Comment: It works, but I now have 0 1 2 3 ... in the first row of my table ?

Comment: See the updated answer with how to set suppress_row in the col_options.